# Extracting data between two tags of xml using regular expression in expression of informatica

Tags: regex, expression, etl, informatica

Scenario: Data is being read from a relation source.
1 column is having blob(XML) data.
I have to extract value which available btw two tags.

sample data of blob(XML) column:

```
"**<Details><Action>XYZ</Action><All_ind>UNALL</All_ind><Area>1231</Area><class>D</class>**
**<Details><Action>RAM</Action><All_ind>DELE</All_ind><Area>000</Area><class>C</class>**
**<Details><Action>DEL</Action><All_ind>PUN</All_ind><Area>1112</Area><class>A</class>**
**<Details><Action>ABC</Action><All_ind></All_ind><Area>898</Area><class></class>**
**<Details><Action>BBB</Action><All_ind>123</All_ind><Area>NULL</Area><class>U</class>**
**<Details><Action>TWO</Action><All_ind>BACS</All_ind><Area>1212</Area><class>M</class>**
**<Details><Action>YUG</Action><All_ind>UNSCO</All_ind><Area>BHD</Area><class>M</class>**
**<Details><Action>ABC</Action><All_ind>ADD</All_ind><Area>DEL</Area><class>P</class>**"
```

desired output:

```
XYZ UNALL 1231 D
RAM DELE 000 C
DEL PUN 1112 A
ABC (NULL) 898 (NULL)
BBB 123 NULL U
TWO BACS 1212 M
YUG UNSCO BHD M
ABC ADD DEL
```

I am using below transformation and REG_EXTRACT logic:

```
SOURCE--->EXP(REG_EXTRACT(blob_COLUMN,'Action.?>(.*.?)<\/)')
```

Please guide me in correct direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If available, consider using a xml parser instead of regex.

Comment: you can use `xml parser`. But i found `SELECT` clause to parse the data is easy. Here is an example - how to read xml data from sql-server. You can see the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65898532/informatica-query-xml-data-in-sql-server-through-odbc

Comment: @kaushik I am using IDQ and its doesn't have XML parser. SELECT You have provided doesn't work for me

Comment: you have to modify accordingly - i mean path should be correct and you need to see if this works against your DB.